# Why does Google recommend wrapping a stylesheet link in a noscript?

Tags: pageload, pagespeed

Just noticed this odd piece of advice on Google's PageSpeed docs:

**https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery**

They recommend converting short external stylesheets to inline `<style>` elements, to avoid blocking. I understand why you might want to do that.

But in their example code, they retain the link to the external stylesheet, but they just move it to the bottom and wrap it in a `<noscript>` element. They haven't made it clear what they're hoping to achieve with this.

What is their reasoning?

Comment: "The original small.css is loaded after onload of the page. The application order of CSS rules is maintained by injecting all the <style> and <link> elements into the document through javascript." What don't you understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<style>` only contains **a subset of all CSS rules** to get some initial styling (in the example case only the `.blue` rule). You still need the full css file, but it's only loaded after page load. And in case JS is disabled, it's ensured to always load. If JS is enabled, it's deferred until the page is fully loaded (otherwise the link tag would block rendering.)

> The original small.css is loaded after onload of the page. The application order of CSS rules is maintained by injecting all the  and  elements into the document through javascript.

Comment: "If JS is enabled, it's deferred until the page is fully loaded". Surely it *never* gets loaded if it's in a noscript? Or are they saying you should write some JavaScript to make this work (which they haven't bothered including in the example)? If that's what they're suggesting, they've made it amazingly unclear

Comment: That's exactly what they're saying with "by injecting all the <style> and <link> elements into the document through javascript.". And yes, it is amazingly unclear. They could have added another sentence or maybe even an example script (they must be having some sort of reference implementation).

Comment: Wow that's a really weird thing to recommend as a best practice. Stupid advice in my opinion :) Thanks for confirming